# Interruption of a os.rename in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, python-os

I made a script in python that renames all files and folders(does not *recurse*) in "." directory: the directory in which file is kept. It happened that I ran the script in a directory which contained no files and only one directory let's say **imp** with path `.\imp`. While program was renaming it, the electricity went off and the job was interrupted (sorry did't had UPS).

Now as the name suggests, assume *imp* contains important data. The renaming process also took quite good time ( compared to others ) before electricity went off even when all it was renaming was one folder. After this endeavour is some data corrupted, lost or anything?

Just make this more useful: what happens os.rename is **forced** to stop when it is doing its job? How is the effect different for files and folders?

### Details

**Python Version** - 2.7.10

**Operating System** - Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Windows, which means you are (probably) on NTFS.  NTFS is a modern, [journaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) file system.  It should not *corrupt* or *lose* any data, though it's possible that only some of the changes that constitute a rename have been applied (for instance, the filename might change without updating the modification time, or *vice-versa*).  It is also possible that none of those changes have been applied.

Note the word "should" is not the same as "will."  NTFS *should not* lose data in this fashion, and if it does, it's a bug.  But because all software has bugs, it is important to keep backups of files you care about.